# Check condition ifelse statement in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

It is possible to check many conditions with for loop in a ifelse statement ?
For example :

```
param1=c("Var_10","Var_11","Var_12")
param2=c("Var_22","Var_23","Var_24")

df[,"myVar"] <- ifelse((df[,param1[1]]<df[,param2[1]]) & 
                                                                (df[,param1[2]]<df[,param2[2]]) & 
                                                                (df[,param1[3]]<df[,param2[3]]),1,0)
```

If I have 4 values in param1 and param2 : add the condition `(df[,param1[4]]<df[,param2[4]])`.

Comment: You could use nested `ifelse` function calls, but I would look at `dplyr::case_when` instead

Comment: Thanks ! param1 and param2 must have the same lenght but those are arguments of a function. Their lengths can be 3:10. Is there a way to check **n conditions** depends of parm1 and parm2 lengths ?